# Transactions disabled

Tags: phantom-wallet

Recently I am having a major issue with Phantom wallet. I am using chrome browser extension Whenever I try to send fund from my wallet I got an error message saying " transactions disabled ". I contacted customer support many times but they advised me to contact legal support team. Still no response from legal team. What should I do to to resolve my issue ? I am in great trouble now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear this. Please continue to follow the guidance from Phantom support. Available via settings > help & support. They are best equipped to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. No clue why. Sent a message to their legal team as instructed. In the meantime, took my keys and imported the wallet into another Solana provider. No reason for this nonsense at all.